# Table mapping in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and am not sure I am getting the results I expect, although that doesn't mean they are wrong.

I have 2 classes Property and PropertyGuestAmenity

When I run the console command to update the schema, I get 2 tables generated. property and property_guest_amenity. Which is as I expect.

The 2 tables are linked together and I have set up the table maps as

In Property

```
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PropertyGuestAmenity",
inversedBy="properties")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="property_amenity_map")
      */
     protected $amenities;
```

In PropertyGuestAmenity

```
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Property", inversedBy="amenities")
  */
 protected $property=null;
```

When I run the schema update it generates the property_amenity_map table I
expect it to, but it also generates propertyguestamenity_property which looks to be the same as the property_amenity_map but with the fields in the reverse order.

Am I doing something wrong or is that normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relations, one side is inversedBy, the other site is mapped by. A little caveat.

So, in  your PropertyGuestAmenity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Property", mappedBy="amenities")
 */
protected $property=null;
```

Comment: That fixed it to what I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem in your declaration who let doctrine think you have to manytomany relations.

The first is inversed by "properties", the second by "amenities". But in your second class you have only "property" (no "properties").

So Doctrine made 2 relations.